# Using an interface in contracts for its own functions

Tags: racket

This example illustrates my problem:

I'd like to define a common interface for several kinds of collections. Of particular interest is the binary `add-all` method, which both takes and returns a `collection`. And I'd like the language to do as much checking for me as possible, so I put a contract on it.

```
(define collection
   (interface ()
     <other stuff>  
     [add-all (->m (is-a?/c collection) (is-a?/c collection))]))
```

This, of course, gives an error:

```
 collection: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
```

How can I use the `collection` interface within contracts for methods of `collection`?

I tried using letrec, but it didn't work, because this example uses `collection` before it's initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [`recursive-contract`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/contract-utilities.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fcontract%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._recursive-contract%29%29) and it apparently works:

```
(define collection
   (interface ()
     [add-all (->m (recursive-contract (is-a?/c collection))
                   (recursive-contract (is-a?/c collection)))]))
```